# Using Plupload with amazon s3 and asp.net MVC C#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, amazon-s3, plupload

I am trying to use plupload http://www.plupload.com/ to upload images to an amazon s3 bucket and I want to also store the images urls in a sql server using asp.net MVC to be able to use them in the future. I am incredibly lost on exactly what to do. All the articles have really confused me.

Please help me in:

1) Re-size images to a maximum width and height on client size.

2) Upload images directly to amazon s3 (showing a progress bar).

3) Store image location in a database. 
(How to link with plupload with MVC C# given that files are uploaded to s3 directly)

Comment: Are you trying to handle these functions yourself? with different buttons? if its like so, i think you should just call some Java Functions as its name them

Comment: I think there is a way to do so using plupload but I am quite confused on how to configure it.

Comment: @Marwan, I'm looking to do something similar i.e. upload directly to s3 using plupload, but save file info in db. Any chance you got this working and could point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can help with the post directly the S3 part.

I created a sample MVC3 app and put it on Github. It's currently setup for videos but if you change the content-type and some of the plupload settings it will easily work for images. This Ruby on Rails examples is configured for images:

https://github.com/iwasrobbed/Rails3-S3-Uploader-Plupload

Details on my blog:

http://blog.cdeutsch.com/2011/07/aspnet-mvc3-app-using-plupload-to.html

Github:

https://github.com/crdeutsch/MVC3PluploadToAmazonS3